# HttpClient doesn't retry after exception

Tags: apache, httpclient, ioexception

I am having this issue with the HttpClient where it doesn't make any try to the server after an exception has occured.

I have initially used **CloseableHttpClient** to establish a connection and what I found was that it was throughing **IOException** from time to time. 
This could be for different reasons but I thought the client will attempt to connect to the server a few times. However that didn't seem to be the case.
My understanding is that CloseableHttpClient closes the connection after the statement has been executed and/or an exception as occured and therefore there are no retries.

I looked at the **HttpClient** and in the documentation it states that automatic retries occur when the client can't establish a connection

> Per default HttpClient will automatically attempt to recover from the
>   not-fatal errors, that is, when a plain IOException is thrown.
>   HttpClient will retry the method three times provided that the request
>   has never been fully transmitted to the target server. For a detailed
>   discussion on HTTP method recovery please refer to the HttpClient
>   exception handling guide

So if an IOException occurred, there should be more tries.

What approach should I use to make sure that when the client tries to establish a connection with the server, upon failure it tries a couple of times more?

```
 private Map<String, String> queryResults(String query) throws OrnClientException {

        try  {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(concatURL));
            final String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            return extractMapFromQueryResults(result);
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
```

**httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(concatURL));**

This is where I'm getting the IOException.

Comment: Where's the code related to your question?

Comment: I have update my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that when you create your client you use a [DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler.html)

This should retry your request the number of times you set it, as long as its not one of the default exceptions.